# SUM at List<> in C#

Tags: c#, listview

I have this code:

```
NpsViewModelList = (ParseStoreName(result.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateSubmit).SimplePaged(page, _limit).ToList())),

NpsViewModelList2 = (ParseStoreName(result.OrderBy(x => x.DateSubmit).SimplePaged(page, _limit).ToList())),
```

the sum like =

```
NpsViewModelList + NpsViewModelList2;
```

but it's a list and I can't do this.

I need to sum the results, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean sum, as in mathematically add up all the values of a field, or sum as in combine 2 lists into 1 list?

Comment: Jéssica, please refer to this link to ask better question on SO. You need to post minimalist working code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: is a sum in a combine 2 lists into 1 list

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Concat` two `List<T>` using `Concat` method:

```
var  finalList = NpsViewModelList.Concat(NpsViewModelList);
```

Comment: I used this, but didn´t work and i put toList(), and works... Thanks

Comment: what you mean by does not work

Comment: in my code it´s not work i needed to use NpsViewModelList.Concat(NpsViewModelList2).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sum function.

```
var sum = NpsViewModelList2.Sum(x=>x.Field);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a new collection and add the first 2 collections to it:

```
var combined = new List<TheType>();
combined.AddRange(list1);
combined.AddRange(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ `Concat()`:

```
var result = NpsViewModelList.Concat(NpsViewModelList2).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Slaven. it´s works !!